# Run mysql script from file and put the results into CSV file

Tags: mysql

My question is quite simple, Im using MySql 5.7 (Cloud SQL so I dont have any access to any file in the DB server) and I want to run a sql select statement from file and put the result in CSV file.
what mysql command that can help me on that plz? and I cant write the select statement in the terminal cause its about 60MB. it should be executed from the file

I tried MysqlWorkBench and it run out of memory every time I export the result to csv file. thats why Im  trying to use the command line thinking it'll be much faster and a bit lighter

Any Help plz?

Comment: If you can't use `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` I don't think there's a way to create a CSV directly from MySQL. You'll need to write a script in a programming language that performs the query and creates the CSV from the results.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is use the `mysql` command-line client with the `--batch` option (or `-B` for short).

```
mysql --batch --execute "source myscript.sql"
```

It outputs tab-separated, not comma-separated, but that's easy enough to transform into a format you need.

I don't use MySQL Workbench for any task except designing ER diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mycli](https://mycli.net) to produce a CSV file like so:

`mycli -e '\T csv; source filename.sql'`